# How to create Bokeh plots with image in background?

Tags: python, image, plot, bokeh

I want to create a circle plot with Bokeh, with an image in background, see the code bellow. I can't figure out why the image is not displayed. Is there something wrong in my code, or the method I use is not the proper one?

```
import pandas as pd
import cv2

from bokeh.models import ImageURL, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models.ranges import DataRange1d
from bokeh.io import show

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': [2586, 2836, 2986, 3269, 3702],
                   'X': [120, 210, 80, 98, 40],
                   'Y': [230, 40, 33, 122, 10],
                   'User': ['u1', 'u1', 'u2', 'u2', 'u2']})

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(time=df['Time'], x=df['X'], y=df['Y'], user=df['User']))

#read image
img_url = 'tree.jpg'
image=cv2.imread(img_url)

sx = image.shape[1]
sy = image.shape[0]
x_range = DataRange1d(start = 0, end = sx, bounds = (0, sx), range_padding = 5, range_padding_units = 'percent')
y_range = DataRange1d(start = sy, end = 0, bounds = (0, sy), range_padding = 5, range_padding_units = 'percent')
pw = 600
ph = int(pw * sy / sx)

# Create the figure: p
p = figure(x_axis_label='X', y_axis_label='Y', plot_width = pw, plot_height = ph, 
           x_range=x_range, y_range=y_range, match_aspect=True)
p.image_url(url=[img_url], x = 0, y = 0, w = sx, h = sy, anchor="top_right")
p.circle(x='x', y='y', source=source, size=10, color='blue', fill_color='white', alpha=0.8)

show(p)
```

Image
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`img_url` needs to be a proper URL that the resulting page is able to access. A local file system path to a file is not a URL. Unfortunately, you cannot use `image_url` with a local file without using some sort of a web server because web pages cannot access local files for security reasons. Two feasible options that I can think of:

- Use `bokeh serve` with a directory-based app. It will allow you to serve arbitrary files via the `static` directory
- Don't use `image_url`, use `image_rgba`. You already read the whole image, so you can just serve it as data instead of serving it as a URL

If you can't make `image_url` work, try playing with its anchor and make sure that the `url` parameter starts with the name of the directory. I could display the image by creating a directory named `test_app`:

```
test_app
├── main.py
└── static
    └── tree.png
```

where `main.py` has only

```py
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure

p = figure()
p.image_url(url=['/test_app/static/tree.png'],
            x=[0], y=[0], w=[1], h=[1], anchor="bottom_left")

curdoc().add_root(p)
```

It should be run as `bokeh serve test_app`.

Comment: I use bokeh serve, but it still doesn't work. The app include also a select widgets and 3 other sliders which works just fine. Do you think this can cause the issues with image plotting?

Comment: I have updated my answer to give you something to work with.

Comment: Thank you, Eugene. I followed your recommendation and built this app structure. Now the image_url is working, and not interfere at all with the filter widgets.